# Pipe multiline powershell results into multiple arguments in one line

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to write a oneliner that gets unique ids of tif files in a directory, and then runs ImageMajick's convert to combine them together into multipage tifs:

```
convert ..\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_001.tif ..\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_002.tif ..\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_003.tif ..\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_004.tif ua-nws_00000991_all.tif
```

This works, but I'm trying to automate it for a bunch of ids that have several tifs each. For now, I'm just using one id and using "echo" instead of convert:

```
echo "ua-nws_00000991" | % { $id=$_; ls ../image_data | ? { $_.FullName -match $id } | % { 
    echo $_.FullName } | Join-String -Separator '" "' | % { echo '"'$_'"' $id"_all.tif" }
}
```

But I'm having trouble turning the list of files into a list of arguments. I'm getting the following (I've manually made the paths relative for online posting):

```
"
.\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_001.tif" ".\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_002.tif" ".\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_003.tif" "C:\Daniels_Stuff\Classes\Current\grad_ai\project\repo\article-reconstruction\image_data\ua-nws_00000991_004.tif"
ua-nws_00000991_all.tif
```

Before I added the double quotes, convert was interpreting all of the final `$_` as one argument. I'm adding quotes in order to force convert to see them as multiple arguments. But I can't seem to get rid of that newline. I think it might be caused by the final `echo`, but if I replace it with convert, I get the following:

```
convert.exe: unable to open module file `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_\ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\MY\IMAGES\IMAGE_DATA\UA-NWS_00000991_001.TIF C_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/674.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `\ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\MY\IMAGES\IMAGE_DATA\UA-NWS_00000991_001.TIF C' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: no images defined `ua-nws_00000991_all.tif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3241.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I don't understand Powershell's mad syntax, there are two aspects to **ImageMagick** that may help you out...

**Aspect 1 - Filenames on stdin**

Firstly, you can pass a list of filenames to merge into a single TIF on **ImageMagick**'s *stdin* rather than as parameters. So, if you have 3 pages of a book, in 3 files called `p1.tif`, `p2.tif` and `p3.tif`, rather than do:

```
convert p*.tif book.tif
```

you can also do

```
dir /b/s p*tif | convert @- book.tif
```

Whilst I am generating the names above using `DIR /B/S`, I expect you would want to replace that with your Powershell commands.

**Aspect 2 - Multiple images down single pipe**

Secondly, you can pipe multiple images from multiple invocations of `convert` into a further final invocation of `convert` using *"Magick Image File Format"* (`MIFF`) streaming:

Here is one example, where two invocations of `convert` both send an image each to a final `convert` that joins the images from its MIFF input stream:

```
( convert p1.tif MIFF:- & convert p2.tif MIFF:- ) | convert MIFF:- book.tif
```

Here is a slightly different example of the same thing:

```
FOR files *.TIF; DO
   IF this file has the correct id
      convert $this MIFF:-
   ENDIF
ENDDO | convert MIFF:- book.tif
```

Comment: Thanks. Had no idea this was possible. I was able to do it this way as well, which I think is simpler (and I think faster?): `gci ..\image_data\*.tif | group { $_.Name -replace '_\d+\.tif$' } | % { $_.Group.FullName | convert "@-" "$($_.Name)_all.tif" }`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `Join-String` comes from, but I can only guess that it's broken - because I can't see anywhere else the newline is coming from.

Put some test files in a folder:

```
Name                      
----                      
ua-nws_00000991_001.tif   
ua-nws_00000991_002.tif   
ua-nws_00000991_003.tif   
ua-nws_00000991_004.tif   
ua-nws_00000992_001.tif   
ua-nws_00000992_002.tif   
ua-nws_00000992_003.tif   
ua-nws_00000992_004.tif
```

List them with `Get-ChildItem` (`gci`), and group them (`Group-Object`, aka `group`) by stripping off the trailing number from the filename:

```
PS D:\t\New folder> gci *.tif | group { $_.Name -replace '_\d+\.tif$' }

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                       
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                       
    4 ua-nws_00000991           {D:\t\New folder\ua-nws_00000991_001.tif, D:\t\New folder\ua-nws_00000991_002.tif, D:\t\New folder\ua-nws...
    4 ua-nws_00000992           {D:\t\New folder\ua-nws_00000992_001.tif, D:\t\New folder\ua-nws_00000992_002.tif, D:\t\New folder\ua-nws...
```

Now we have groups, where the group name is the image ID, and the list of files for that ID is the group member. Neat. Now run convert once `foreach` (`%`) group by taking the full filenames as a parameter to convert, and generating a new filename from the group id (`$_.name`) with `_full.tif` on the end:

```
gci *.tif | group { $_.Name -replace '_\d+\.tif$' } |% { Start-Process convert -ArgumentList (@($_.group.fullname) + @("$($_.Name)_full.tif"))}
```

This probably won't work as is, I don't have `convert` installed to try it, and you'll need to adjust the paths. But I think the approach will work.

Comment: NIce solution. In most environments convert without path will resolve to `C:\Windows\system32\convert.exe` and try to make a ntfs volume.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I also learned about `group`, the splat operator, and `Start-Process`!

Comment: Also, `Join-String` is from the [powershell community extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/). It looks like there hasn't been an update in a while, so maybe they were only meant for older powershell versions. I'm on PS 4.

Comment: @xdhmoore useful to know about the splat operator, although this is not using it; this is just `@() + @()` forcing something to be an array, then adding something to it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

```
get-childitem "image_data" -recurse -filter ua-nws_00000991*.tif | % { convert $_.Fullname }
```

Returns all tif files in "image_data" directory and calls `convert` for every found tif file.

hope that helps